# The floor function and a limit

Tags: probability-theory

Is it possible to simlify the follwing expression with a floor function:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n\tau}{T}\right\rfloor-1\right)$$

Comment: Why the tag "probability-theory"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a real number $x$, $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}n=x$. Indeed, $$nx-1\leq\lfloor nx\rfloor\leq nx,$$
then we divide by $n$ and apply squeeze theorem.